# how to chomp the value of an array while in where condition of select query?

Tags: sql, oracle, perl, scripting

I am not able to find how  to chomp the <*> of before value e the 5th value of array  var1.

```
my $sql2 = 'select name, value from A.Database2 minus select name, value from A.database1';

my $sth2 = $dbh1->prepare($sql2);
$sth2->execute();

while ( my @row = $sth2->fetchrow_array ) {

    print join(',', @row), "\n\n";

    chomp;    

    push( @var1, $row[0] );
}

foreach ( @var1 ) {
    print "$_\n";
}

my $sth3 = $dbh->prepare("select name, value from A.database1 where name in (" . join(",", @var1) . ")" ) or die "Can't prepare statement: $DBI::errstr";
$sth3->execute(@var1);

while ( my @row = $sth3->fetchrow_array ) {
    print join(", ", @row), "\n";
}
```

> DBD::Oracle::db prepare failed: ORA-00904: "APR_IMDG_MODE_ENABLED": invalid identifier (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 144 in 'select name,value from A where name in (a,b,c,d,<*>e)') [for Statement "select name,value from A where name in (a,b,c,d,e)"] at hello.pl line 102.
>
> Uncaught exception from user code:
>           Can't prepare statement: ORA-00904: "APR_IMDG_MODE_ENABLED": invalid identifier (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 144 in 'select name,value from  where name in (a,b,c,d,<*>e)') at hello.pl line 102.

Comment: Can't you use a subquery instead of two separate database calls? Do you need the `value` column?

Comment: @Borodin i need to print the name and values column data of table A database1

Comment: `join(",", @var1)` => `qw(?) x @var1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove `<*>` from the beginning of the strings in `@var1` then you can write

```
S/^<\*>// for @var1
```

You also need to quote each element of the `IN` clause, otherwise the values will be treated as column names. You can use `$dbh1->quote` but it's better to use placeholders by building a string of question marks `?, ?, ?, ...` with as many placeholders as there are elements in `@var1`

This should work for you, but I'm not in position to test it at present. Note that it's much better to use upper case language words and a *heredoc* for SQL statements to improve readability

```
s/^<\*>// for @var1;  # remove any indicators

my $pholds = join ', ', ('?') x @var1;  # "?, ?, ?, ?, ?"

my $sth3 = $dbh->prepare(<<END_SQL) or die "Can't prepare statement: $DBI::errstr";
SELECT name, value FROM A.database1
WHERE name IN ($pholds)
END_SQL

$sth3->execute(@var1);

while ( my @row = $sth3->fetchrow_array ) {
    print join(", ", @row), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`chomp` removes trailing whitespace. See `perldoc -f chomp`. It cannot what you want.
To strip leading <> you can use `s/^<>//`

Comment: It doesn't remove trailing whitespace; it specifically removes the text of the input record separator in `$/` which is usually a single linefeed character but  can be set to anything you like.

Comment: @jira Thanks for the reply . i tried using s/^<>//  but  not able to put it in proper place in where condition with quotes .. if possible can u please tell me the syntax.

Comment: OP wants to remove leading chars, no? At least that was my reading. I tried to be short and gave a reference to perldoc for details.

Comment: Yes it seems so (but they actually want to remove `<*>`—the star was swallowed by the markup); I was just correcting your explanation of what `chomp` does. It's not a big deal.